# Matlab - Put elements of structure into an array

Tags: arrays, matlab, vector, structure

```
syms x t 
n=3; a=-1; b=1;
f=@(x) x;
k=@(x,t) x*t;
A=sym('a',[1 n]);
y(x)=A(1);
for i=1:n-1
    y(x)=y(x)+A(1,i+1)*(x^i);
end
I(A)=int((y(x)-f-int(k*y(t),t,a,b))^2,x,a,b)
for i=1:n
    S(i)=diff(I,A(1,i));
end
p=solve(S,A);
```

I want to use all element "p" as polynomial coefficients. 
How to put all elements into an array?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two ways:

**Option 1: Specify the amount of output parameters**

```
[p1,p2,p3] = solve(S, A);
p1 = double(p1);
p2 = double(p2);
p3 = double(p3);
```

**Option 2: Convert the output to an array using `structfun`**

```
p = solve(S,A);
p = structfun(@double, p);
```

Result:

```
p =
     0
     3
     0
```

Comment: There is a third way. "struct2array"